# Porting random permutation code from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab

How can this MATLAB code be translated to Python?

For example with random files:

```matlab
FileA = rand([10,2]);
FileB = randperm(10);

for i=1:10
fileC(FileB(i),1)=FileA(i,1); %for the x
fileC(FileB(i),2)=FileA(i,2); %for the y
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
array_a = np.random.rand(10,2)
array_b = np.random.permutation(range(10))

array_c = np.empty(array_a.shape, array_a.dtype)
for i in range(10):
    array_c[array_b[i], 0] = array_a[i, 0]
    array_c[array_b[i], 1] = array_a[i, 1]
```

Comment: Can I replace 
'array_a = np.random.rand(10,2)
array_b = np.random.permutation(range(10))'
by
'array_a = csv.reader(open(‘C:/testing/FileA.csv’,'rb'),delimeter',')
array_b = csv.reader(open(‘C:/testing/FileB.csv’,'rb'),delimeter',')'  ???

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372910/from-tuple-to-integer-using-csv-files)

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to depend of numpy and you are not dealing with large arrays/performance is not an issue, try this:

```
import random
def randperm(a):
    if(not a):
        return a
     b = []
     while(a.__len__()):
         r = random.choice(a)
         b.append(r)
         a.remove(r)

     return b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import shuffle

def randperm(n):
    lst = [i for i in range(1, n+1)]
    shuffle(lst)
    return lst
```