# from tuple to integer using csv files

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I'm having a little problem using csv.reader.

I have two files:

FileA corresponds to 9 geographical coordinates (x (column1) and y(column2), with no headers). The file is save from excel into a csv file.

```
301506  5918202
301012  5919417
309769  5919926
299337  5924043
299602  5924730
305310  5907794
300634  5927108
303968  5922319
303684  5922062
304882  5922009
```

FileB which is a random sequence of 9 integers between 0 and 8. The file is save as an csv file from excel. The data are in row 1.

```
6     3     7     8     5     1     2     4     0
```

here is the code:

```
import csv

FileA = csv.reader(open(‘FileA.csv’,'rb'),delimeter=',')
coord_list = []
coord_list.extend(FileA)
coordinates = []
for data in coord_list:
     coordinates.append(data[0])
print coordinates

FileB = csv.reader(open(‘FileB.csv’,'rb'),delimeter=',')
seq_list = []
seq_list.extend(FileB)
sequence = []
for data in seq_list:
    sequence.append(data[0])
print sequence


FileC = []

for i range(0,8,1):
         FileC[sequence[i], 1] = coordinates[i,1]
         FileC[sequence[i], 2] = coordinates[i,2]

print FileC
```

but i get :

```
File "C:\generatesequence\script.py", line 19, in <module>
    FileC[sequence[i], 1] = coordinates[i,1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

I want to build the FileC to be able to use it after in ArcMAP

Any advice is welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

`a[b, c]` indexes `a` with the tuple `(b, c)`. You need to think hard about what you *really* want to do at the specific lines where you do this.

Comment: can you be more explicit, i don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You are try to access list with the tuple. Please try `file[sequence[i]: 1] = coordinates[i:1]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I received this error message: 'File "C:\testing\script.py", line 51, in <module>
    file[sequence[i]: 1] = coordinate[i:1]
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is unsubscriptable'

Answer (score 1):

For example

test.csv:
    `'a,b,c,d,f,g'`

```
In [2]: import csv
In [3]: spamReader = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
In [4]: spamReader 
Out[4]: <_csv.reader object at 0x1e34ec0>
In [5]: spamReader.next()
Out[5]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

the csv.reader returns an object is an iterator, not a tuple or list. Hence FileA should be an iterator (you can't directly convert it to list)

Comment: list(iterator) will give [[a,b,c,d,f,g]] not just list of elements

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing lists incorrectly: you cannot access two-dimensional lists using a comma, as you would in R or MATLAB. Please look over [Python lists](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) *very* thoroughly.

Based on your code, I think this should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
import csv

FileA = csv.reader(open(‘C:/testing/FileA.csv’,'rb'),delimeter',')
FileB = csv.reader(open(‘C:/testing/FileB.csv’,'rb'),delimeter',')
FileC = [0] * 10

for lineA, lineB in zip(FileA, FileB):
    FileC[int(lineB[0])] = lineA

print FileC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I obtained the following error:'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str'

Comment: Try edited version above. I changed one line to `FileC[int(lineB[0])] = lineA`

Comment: Actually the number of points is bigger (49 instead of 10), but using your script in the same way (i checked twice for no errors), i obtained: '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ['301506.3', '5918202.4'], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
'

Comment: Please post the contents of your FileA.csv and FileB.csv. Based on what you post, I would guess that fileB.csv always has a 12, at least in column 1, but we really need to see it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me. Please can you have a look at another of my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371555/transform-code-from-matlab-to-python). Basically the code "wim" wrote works perfectly. But my problem is how to use my data within my csv file? Maybe it is easier to import the data using another way with text file?

Comment: The reason that code works is that it uses numpy ndarrays, which can be accessed using commas (regular Python arrays cannot). What do you mean about using the data within a csv file? Could you post the contents of your csv files and explain *clearly* what you are trying to do?